# Lua: Raw Sockets

Tags: windows, sockets, lua, udp

I'm trying to get sockets to work on a port that's already in use.

I know LuaSocket--however I can not get LuaSocket to work on a local port that's already in use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Ports cannot have multiple sockets open there.

Answer (score 0):

As Puppy said, this is impossible.

But, depending on what exactly you want to archive, there might be other solutions.
Is this the server or a client?

Maybe you can interrupt one socket to give the other time to do his work, or so?